# Docker: Error response from daemon: failed to get digest sha256

Tags: docker

I having error while i trying to commit my container.

```
$ docker ps -a

5c181bc0f656   4dd97cefde62   "/bin/bash"   8 hours ago   2 hours ago   chatbot

$ docker container commit 5c181bc0f656 chatbottz3/chatbottz-233:1

Error response from daemon: failed to get digest sha256:4dd97cefde62cf2d6bcfd8f2c0300a24fbcddbe0ebcd577cc8b420c29106869a: open /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/4dd97cefde62cf2d6bcfd8f2c0300a24fbcddbe0ebcd577cc8b420c29106869a: no such file or directory
```

Please, help me. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by redownloading the image used by the container because i deleted it before

Answer (score 2):

It could be probably related to new containerd integration in Docker Desktop that makes a lot of changes in your image size calculator. This is about WASM integration and it is in beta right now so if you don't need to use it you could deactivate it in settings, but you'll need to rebuild any image you had before the changes.

As mentioned here in Docker docs, WASM is still in beta so you need to be careful if using it with your image size calculator
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/wasm/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wonderful, I disable wasm feature and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I got the same case. My container based on ubuntu and when I redownloading the image, image id has changed. so commit is still fail. finally, i export the container and import again, a new image created ^_^